# I am trying to read a CSV file in C#, splitting lines into groups depending on word repition. I am getting an index out of range error

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2012

my error is on the very last line, saying my index is out of range. Not sure what the problem is. I would like to continue using a list of lists or lists. I am trying to read a line of a csv file and separate that line into groups if one of the words in that line repeats; for example:

"hey how are you hey whats up"

hey how are you would be in one group and then hey whats up would be in the other group.

```
string[] ReadDirectory = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\-------", "*.csv");

List<List<List<string>>> myList = new List<List<List<string>>>();

List<string> CSVlist = new List<string>();

foreach (string file in ReadDirectory)
{
    using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        int groupIndex = 0;

        string line = readFile.ReadLine();

        string[] headers = line.Split(',');

        Array.Reverse(headers);

        CSVlist.Add(headers[headers.Length - 1]);

        myList.Add(new List<List<string>>());

        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (headers[i].Contains("repeats") && headers[i + 1].Contains("repeats"))
            {

                 myList.Add(new List<List<string>>());

                 groupIndex++;
            }        
            myList[0][groupIndex].Add(headers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The core problem is of course a `List<List<List<...>>>`. That's silly, write out some useful classes.

Answer (score 0):

the problem resides when `i =headers.Length-1`, then  `headers[i + 1]` is out of bounds. try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
{
  if (i<headers.Length-1)
  {
   if (headers[i].Contains("repeats") && headers[i + 1].Contains("repeats"))
   {
     myList.Add(new List<List<string>>());
     groupIndex++;
   }        
   myList[0][groupIndex].Add(headers[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: okay, I see what you're saying. However, your suggestion did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I'm not sure it'll do what you want it too (eg. if headers contains the exact word 'repeats', but this may just be example code so I'll ignore that) - but I'll focus on the error reported.

The exact error you reported is caused by this line:

```
myList[0][groupIndex].Add(headers[i]);
```

When you first add a nested list to `myList`, you don't add a nested list to that first nested list - so when the if statement is false, it tries to add the header into myList[0][0] where the second index is out of range because there is no inner list at myList[0].

Changing

```
myList.Add(new List<List<string>>());
```

to something like

```
var innerGroupList = new List<string>();
var groupList = new List<List<string>>();
groupList.Add(innerGroupList);
myList.Add(groupList);
```

will resolve the issue, but you won't get your expected outcome from the example data as the word 'repeats' is not there, you would need to do something like save each word in a Hashset, and check each word against that. If it already exists in the dictionary, split it into another group.